# Show the sequence ${x_n}$ is monotonically increasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

So here is a question from the book 'Problems in Mathematical Analysis by W.J. Kaczor and M.T. Nowak'. I tried to solve this problem and I'll attach my solution in this question. Please let me know whether my solution is correct or not. And most likely its not correct then I would like to request the reader to give a pure solution.

Question: Let ${a_1}$,${a_2}$,...,${a_p}$ be fixed positive numbers. Consider the sequence

$${s_n}=\frac{{a_1}^n+{a_2}^n+...+{a_p}^n}{p}$$ and ${x_n}={s_n}^\frac{1}{n}, n \in \Bbb N$.

Show that the sequence $\{x_n \}$ is monotonically increasing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5DPM.jpg)

Comment: Do not use images to ask your question

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: "If a bounded sequence converges then it has to be monotonic" is wrong, for example $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. In fact all convergent sequences are bounded.

Comment: Edit: sniped
Not an answer, but it simply isn't true that a convergent bounded sequence has to be monotonic. It can oscillate in small amounts. Take 1, 1-1/2, 1 - 1/2 + 1/3, ...

Comment: This is the standard power mean inequality. The proof I have seen uses Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @MorA. But here sequence is positive term sequence and also have a unique limit point so doesn't it implies monotonicity? Also can you give me a counter example for positive term sequence sir ?

Comment: @DamianPavlyshyn Sir I'm a new user, its hard to write down each step in text but I'll try to not use images now onwards

Comment: @martycohen I'll check it out sir

Comment: @martycohen I would like to request you to please help me out with one issue, i was thinking to post this query as a question but that won't be a good idea , Sir I'm trying to solve problems from the book "Problems in Mathematical Analysis by Kaczor" and I have no professor to help me out. I just wanted to know which BOOKS or Text will help me out the most to solve such Problems. I hope you will reply me in your free time. Thank you sir

Comment: I can't help you directly, but you might check the references in Wikipedia articles on the subjects you are interested in. You could also look into online courses such as Coursera and Kahn Academy.

Comment: @martycohen okay Sir I'll check them out thanks for replying me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function $f(x) = x^{(n + 1)/n}$ is convex then :
$$\dfrac{f(a_1^n) + \cdots + f(a_p^n)}{p} \geq f \left(\dfrac{a_1^n + \cdots + a_p^n}{p}\right)$$
so :
$$\dfrac{a_1^{n + 1} + \cdots + a_p^{n + 1}}{p} \geq \left(\dfrac{a_1^n + \cdots + a_p^n}{p}\right)^{(n + 1)/n}$$
We deduce that :
$$s_{n + 1} \geq s_n^{(n + 1)/n}$$
and finally :
$$x_{n + 1} = \left(s_{n + 1}\right)^{1/(n + 1)} \geq \left(s_n\right)^{1/n)} = x_n$$
the sequence $(x_n)$ is then increasing

Comment: Sir do you have any specific document or something so that I can learn about convex property of a function. You solution is just too clear, I loved it thank you

Comment: Convex functions and their applications : https://carmamaths.org/resources/jon/Preprints/Books/CUP/CUPold/np-convex.pdf

Comment: Thank you sir for the doc

Comment: You're welcome. i hope this helps.